# Application Insights analytics Let operator

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

what is wrong with the following query?:

```
let errIds = exceptions
| where operation_Name == "My Special Operation" 
| summarize by operation_Id
traces
| where operation_Name == "My Special Operation" and operation_Id !in (errIds)
| summarize count() by operation_Id
```

I'm trying to get operations that did not generated a exception...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, all i was missing was a `;` after the `let` statement

Answer (score 1):

To get traces that didn't generate an exception, how about doing a [`join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-reference#join-operator) with `exceptions` as shown below. Set the kind of `join` to `anti` so that it gets **all traces that don't have any associated exceptions**.

```
traces
    | where operation_Name == "My Special Operation"
    | join kind=anti (exceptions) on operation_Id
    | summarize count() by operation_Id
```